# Записать в файл то, что процедура ввыводит на консоль

Tags: c#

У меня вызывается метод.

```
public void doSomethingElse()
{
    Debug.WriteLine(color);
}
```

Сам метод выводит на консоль строку. Как мне после вывода строки на консоль, выведенную информацию записать в файл. Изначально переменную не могу записать в файл так как выполняю юнит тесты.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, приведите свой код, тогда можно будет дать более развернутый ответ, исходя из конкретной ситуации.

Comment: ну так вынесите код формирования строки в отдельный метод и уже этот метод проверяйте тестами.

Comment: для тестирования записи в файл - сравнивайте записанную и прочитанную информацию, тесты вполне позволяют писать в MemoryStream например, но можно и во временный файл писать.

Comment: @rdon у меня есть пример, но он на джаве 
`public void testDoSomethingElse() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("d:\\temp.txt"); //  создаем файл
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file); 
    PrintStream standardOut = System.out;
    System.setOut(ps); // присваиваем файловый поток в качестве основного
    penWithThreeArgs.doSomethingElse(); // вызываем метод
    Assert.assertEquals(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.toURI())).get(0), col); // проверяем что результат в файле равен ожидаемому
    System.setOut(standardOut); // возвращаем метод в исходное состояние
}`

Comment: Не уверен что перенаправление потока вывода - хорошая идея. Методы вывода в консоль, сами по себе, в тестировании не нуждаются. Тестировать необходимо подготовленный для вывода результат.

Comment: Единственное исключение из этого правила - если вы тестируете чужую консольную программу методом "черного ящика", тогда перенаправление потоков оправдано.

Comment: @rdorn ну просто я учусь тестированию, и если будет большой кусок кода, то неприятно будет оттуда всё перебирать)

Comment: тогда читайте тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5 Если кратко, есть три стандартных потока ввода вывода, которые использует класс Console, и три метода для их установки, на случай, если стандартные не подходят. И, ни чего личного, прежде чем учиться тестированию, неплохо бы освоить использование документации, без этого много не на тестируете, или на тестируете не то что нужно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У механизмов отладочного вывода (`Debug.WriteLine`) и трассировки (`Trace.WriteLine`) есть стандартные способы перенаправления - [Trace Listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx).

По умолчанию вывод `Debug.WriteLine` уходит вникуда, т.к. ни одного Trace Listener-а для него не задано. При отладке сам отладчик (студия) добавляет Trace Listener, который перенаправляет вывод в окно отладчика (Output), а вовсе не на консоль.

Так что вам не надо перенаправлять вывод на консоль в файл. Вам нужно просто добавить стандартный [`TextWriterTraceListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx) в `Debug.Listeners` и вы получите копию отладочного вывода в файле. Вот минимальный код:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // в инициализации тестов, один раз
            Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("log.txt"));

            Debug.WriteLine("test");

            // после прогона тестов 
            // чтобы записать буфер на диск и не потерять хвост лога
            Debug.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

При трассировке (использовании `Trace.WriteLine`) listener-ы можно задавать прямо в конфиге, это достаточно [подробно расписано в howto в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<configuration>  
  <system.diagnostics>  
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />  
        <remove name="Default" />  
      </listeners>  
    </trace>  
  </system.diagnostics>  
</configuration>
```

---

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Test message.");  
// You must close or flush the trace to empty the output buffer.  
Trace.Flush();
```

Comment: А почему `Flush()` обязателен? Там что, никакого `Dispose` или финанализатора нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет. Дикари-с. Есть autoflush, который флюшит на диск после каждой записи и потенциально бьет по производительности.

Comment: Тогда надо от него унаследоваться и приделать :)

Comment: @Qwertiy там кстати внутри есть реализованный Dispose/Finalize (через Dispose(bool)), но нет именно финализатора. И добавление финализатора особо не поможет, т.к. в момент вызова финализатора граф объектов уже разобран, и Trace Listener просто не может зафлюшить свой буфер в File Stream (потому что тот сам по себе финализируемый и скорее всего уже мертв и закрыт).

Comment: Хм.. Задумался... А как другие SreamWriter'ы справляются с этой проблемой?

Comment: @Qwertiy точно так же - никак :). Стандартный StreamWriter точно так же теряет собственный буфер при сборке мусора. Легко проверить однострочником `File.CreateText("log2.txt").WriteLine("something");`

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо большое) всё понятно)

Comment: @PashaPash, надо какое-нибудь OnBeforeDispose изобретать)))